# Restart Computer via Flex Application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, command-prompt

I need to restart the computer via a Flex Application, I tried these methods :

1st

```
    var process:NativeProcess;          
    var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/reboot.bat");
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file; 
    process = new NativeProcess();
    process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

2nd

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var mp:File = new File();
mp = mp.resolvePath('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe');
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = mp;
var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
args.push('shutdown.exe /s /t 00');
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;
var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

Finally, in here I have my file inside a directory named fscommand in the same directory containing the main application

```
fscommand("exec", "reboot.bat");
```

and the reboot.bat contain `shutdown.exe /s /t 00`

But none of this works ... can anyone help me with this ^^ Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to run a browser based application or an AIR application?  What is the problem with either of the methods you discuss?  Do you get errors?  Honestly, the thought of any application being able to restart my computer gives me willies.  [I get angry enough when Microsoft Update does it]

Comment: @Reboog711 Lol, we do need the restart after the updates, and it's an AIR application. I guess the third method is just wrong, but for the other 2, I don't get any Error, and nothing happens too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing is write a Native application using C++ or VB. using sockets, invoke the shutdown/restart command from air application onto this native application.

If you are trying to access anything other than the working directory of the AIR, it is a sandbox violation, AIR applications cannot access the contents of the Windows system32 folder. You have to use a third party application for doing this.

Comment: I see, Thank you, can you give me any link of documentation about this ?

Comment: Done and working perfectly ^^; if any one want, this is a very good tutorial : [Here is the link](http://www.screencast.com/users/Quetwo/folders/Trainings/media/e9663761-67e8-4f2b-8f6c-e7d5214d2f85)